# How to insert an option into a select in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have the following piece of javascript. jQuery is not available and I'm forced into IE7 mode:

```
function insertOpt(idx, newopt)
{
    var l = sel.options.length;
    var ix = idx;
    if (ix < 0)
        ix = l;

    for (var i=l; i>ix; i--)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = sel.options[i-1].value;
        opt.innerHTML = sel.options[i-1].innerHTML;
        sel.options[i] = opt;
    }

    sel.options[ix] = newopt;
}
```

The first time through the select is empty, so the `for` loop does nothing and it falls over on the last line of the function `sel.options[ix] = newopt;` with the error:

```
Object does not support this property or method
```

This function works in latest version of IE, but not in IE7 mode.

Can anyone give me an IE7 equivalent of this function please?

The function is passed an option which is to be inserted at the passed index.  All other options (if any) are moved up one and the new one is inserted.

In this initial case the value passed for idx is 0.

`sel` is a global variable which has been populated like so:

```
sel = document.getElementById("myselect");
```

Comment: You can do it exactly like you should do it in other browsers. i.e. create an option element and append/insert it to a selection element. `innerHTML` is not a part of that process ...

Comment: Option element has `text` and `value` properties. Use them instead of `innerHTML` (which is read-only for options in old IEs).

Comment: Then [insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) instead of appending ...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but getting the error mentioned

Comment: No, you're setting `opt.innerHTML` as where you should set `opt.text` ...

Comment: I can change innerHTML to text, that's not where I'm having the problem

Comment: I have changed innerHTML to text and now it works.  That makes no sense to me, as the error was not on that line.  Strange behaviour - but it works - thank you

Comment: Well, I've learned that you can't trust on line numbers old IEs show you in error messages.